# Null reference exception on pre-production environment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got WinForms application that I'm constantly developing on Windows 10 machine. This application is deployed then to windows 2003 server where some before release tests are performed. The problem with null reference exception occurs when application is closing. What are typical approaches in such situation to check what's the problem is. This issue occurs only on these machine, I can't install visual studio here. What should I try to use to discover such issue?

Comment: Add some logging on application closing and check stacktrace.Also do you have any information in windows events?

Comment: Deploy the PDB symbols and you can get the line numbers in the stacktrace too.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the PDB symbol files to the test environment you should get line numbers in your exception stack traces.

Beyond that you might be able to install the [remote debugging tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) and connect to the failing instances from your development IDE.

You could also log messages to a file to help you narrow down the issue.